# Swagger codegen delegatePattern for Spring Boot with HttpServletRequest in method paremeters

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, pom.xml, swagger-codegen

Currently I have a project that uses the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to generate the swagger controllers with the `delegatePattern`.

`pom.xml`:

```
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-api-v1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/specs/v1.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>spring</language>
                <apiPackage>test.foo.bar.v1</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>test.foo.bar.v1.v1.model</modelPackage>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <configOptions>
                    <java8>true</java8>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                    <useOptional>true</useOptional>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
[...]
```

Currently it generates the controller interfaces like this:

```
public interface FooApi {

    FooDelegate getDelegate();

    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "fooAction", notes = "", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class)
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fooAction",
        produces = { "text/plain" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<String> fooAction() {
        return getDelegate().fooAction();
    }

}
```

But I like that the controller is generated with an `HttpServletRequest` as parameters like this:

```
public interface FooApi {

    FooDelegate getDelegate();

    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "fooAction", notes = "", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class)
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fooAction",
        produces = { "text/plain" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<String> fooAction(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return getDelegate().fooAction(request);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to make this happen?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can inject the HttpServletRequest into your delegate/class controller like this:

```
public class FooApiController implements FooApi {
  private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

  @Autowired
  public FooApiController(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
  }

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<String> fooAction() {
    // code here
  }
}
```

Spring is aware of the nature of the HttpServletRequest and automatically its scope is always set to request and it isn't a Singleton. So you will always have the current request at hand.

Answer (score 0):

[Rainerhahnekamp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53435755/10215969) worked for me.
Another way, I found working is to use @Scope with @Context.

```
@Scope("request")
public class FooApiController implements FooApi {
   
   @Context
   private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
   ...
   Your code goes here
   ...

}
```